# How to create specific URIs for users in FIREBASE WEB javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a firebase project developed in javscript html and css that works like a social network, I have users in my database and these users have profile information to show.

The problem is, I want to associate each user to a specific URI so everyone can use that link to access a user's info.

Example:

I want to generate a link for users like "https://myproject.com/users/john-doe" (for user john doe) and i want it to bring to that specific user page.

I'm using firebase hosting and there is something for rewriting urls but I couldn't see anything to suit my case, it's the entire week I'm looking to solve this problem and still haven't found something yet, please help, thank you!

Comment: try a few lines of code yourself, or you have already done so, post it here to complement your question, making it more clear and specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is a single-page application, where a single HTML+JavaScript page is handling many URLS - dynamically generating the content.

You'll need to implement multiple steps:

1. Configure Firebase Hosting to direct multiple incoming URLs to the same HTML page. This is done with a [`rewrite` rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites) in your `firebase.json` file, such as:

   ```
   "rewrites": [ {
     "source": "**",
     "destination": "/index.html"
   } ]
   ```
2. Now the JavaScript of your `index.html` page can inspect the URL in `window.location.href`, extract the user name from it, and then serve the correct content for that user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I should have explained better, sorry, mine is not a single-page application, my problem was about users, but i will have to handle other things that will have the same behaviour. There will be users URIs, user's skill URIs (e.g. "good in speaking in public") and user's jobs URIs so i will have different paths like

"https://myproject.com/users/john-doe" for users
"https://myproject.com/skills/speaking-skill" for skills
"https://myproject.com/jobs/developer" for jobs

each link should bring to a specific page that will display all information about what you look 4